# SQL - reducing duplication in SELECT and WHERE clause

Tags: sql, performance, readability

Excuse the ambiguous title. But is there a way I can reduce duplication in SQL with the following query:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Address1))
FROM Customers
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(Address1)) = Address2
```

Notice `LTRIM(RTRIM(Address1))` is duplicated? Can I avoid this

Comment: Do you use `SQL Server/Sybase`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct way:

Trim your data and store it in clean form if possible.

---

Alternatively use subquery and decide if it is more readable:

```
SELECT Address1
FROM (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Address1)) AS Address1, Address2
      FROM Customers) AS sub
WHERE Address1 = Address2
```

Comment: Thanks - it works. Is it running the SELECT twice however? Just wondering in terms of efficiency.

Comment: @keldar Use both queries, highlight them, check `show execution plan` and compare. I guess there should be no difference. Query optimizer is smart enough

Comment: @keldar This is the right answer. The script provided above is a workaround for the "correct way". If you are looking for "efficiency", then resolve this using the correct way i.e. **Trim your data and store it in clean form if possible.**. Otherwise, this query as well as yours will only have a marginal difference in terms of execution plan, I suppose.

Comment: SARGability is irrelevant, because there is no `JOIN` and the two address values are in the same row.